# Is there a way to get an alert when the azure cloud service is unresponsive or busy?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Is there a way to get an alert when the cloud service is Unresponsive or Busy? I've only seen options on how to create an alert about metrics but not really on status.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, Azure do not provide such alerts and you need to manually [troubleshoot Cloud Services roles that fail to start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-troubleshoot-roles-that-fail-start).

You may leave your feedback here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

---

Alternatively, if you're open to using the third party services, such as AzureWatch. It can alert your instance becomes Unresponsive or busy.

[CloudMonix](http://www.cloudmonix.com/features/azure-management/cloud-services-monitoring/) tracks and visualizes key performance indicators for Cloud Services, and sends automatic notifications whenever issues arise or individual instances are unavailable. Additionally, it provides highly sophisticated automation platform that allows to add or remove Cloud Role instances according to the demand or reboot existing instances on a daily schedule or after crash.